# How to make an object move relative to itself

Tags: processing, move

I'm trying to make a game where you use w,s,a,d keys to move and I want to characters to move relative to themselves.

Instead of moving up or down in the X or Y direction it moves forwards and backwards or turns left to right. Kind of like how the game Tank Trouble moves.

If anyone has an idea on how to do this please let me know!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I am sure somebody has an idea here but in order to help you out we need you to provide description of what you tried, minimal code example and a precise question you have. Please refer to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different approaches you can take to solve this problem:

- If you're only ever dealing with right angles, e.g. if turning right always turns you 90 degrees to the right, then you can use an enum to track which direction you're facing. Modify that enum when you press left or right, and use that enum to choose which direction to move when you press up or down.
- If you need to deal with more angles, e.g. if turning right only turns 1 degree to the right, then you need to use some basic trigonometry to track the direction the user is facing.

For the second approach, you should research [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). Instead of using X and Y coordinates directly in your movement, you would use an angle and a speed. Then the `cos()` and `sin()` functions will give you the x and y based on those values.

Something like this:

```
float deltaX = cos(angle) * speed;
float deltaY = sin(angle) * speed;
player.x += deltaX;
player.y += deltaY;
```

Then you'd want to modify the `angle` and `speed` variables when the user presses a key.

Comment: What do the player.x and player.y do?

Comment: @CarterMoseley Those are just examples. It's however you're currently storing the position of your player.

Comment: Sorry. Im just not getting it to work. I think I made it more complex than it needs to be. Is there any way to find the x and y coordinate once the object has moved?

Comment: Is there anyway I could use this multiple times though. Say I want to object to move forward 20 meters, then turn right 23 degrees and go forward 10 meters. Like it works if I want to object to only go around one circle with a center foci but not move around.

Comment: @CarterMoseley You'd keep track of the x and y values in variables. You wouldn't need to find the values, because you're already have them.